# Ember JS: Passing parameters to Model.save() for custom API

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

I'm working on an Ember.js application using Ember Data on a somewhat unusual [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/).

To query an item from that API the URL looks like `/singleitem?collection_id=1&item_id=2` To fetch the data I'm using this model hook:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
export default Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return this.store.query('singleitem', {item:params.item_id, collection:params.collection_id});
    }
});
```

In a component I show data from the API in an `<input type="text">` field and when the user changes the content I want the component to update my model and write it back to my API:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
    async change() {
        this.test.set('title', 'Hello World!');
        await this.test.save();
    }
});
```

This code sends a PATCH request to `/singleitem/2` where `2` is the 'id' property from the response of the JSON API item.

How can I pass parameters to `save()` so that the PATCH request is sent to `/singleitem?collection_id=1&item_id=2` – just like I've been able to do in `this.store.query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the `url` of any operation, then you need to modify your `adapter`. If you are using the default adapter, you need to create one for your entity. See from [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/)

[RESTAdapter](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.10/classes/DS.RESTAdapter) and [JSONAPIAdapter](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.10/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter) have methods to modify each type of request's endpoints, such as: `urlForUpdateRecord`, `urlForQuery` etc.

I think what you need is to modify [`urlForUpdateRecord`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.10/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/urlForUpdateRecord?anchor=urlForUpdateRecord). Such as:

```
urlForUpdateRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
  const collectionId = 1;
  // you need to change with correct value of `collectionId`

  return `?collection_id=${collectionId}&item_id=${id}`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I had to return the whole path `return \`/singleitem?collection=${collectionId}&item=${id}\`;` as otherwise the request would be `/singleitem/1/2?collection_id=1&item_id=2`.